# styled-component stopped working after refactoring

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

styled-components stopped working.
I could use styled-components without any trouble,
but after finish refactoring (creating child components),
suddenly some styled components stopped working.

```
import React from "react"; 
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import MainWindow from "./components/mainWindow";
import SubWindow from "./components/subWindow";
import "./index.css";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.main`
display: flex;
`;

const App = () => {
 return (
 <Container>
   <MainWindow />
   <SubWindow />
 </Container>
 );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

styled-components assign class name to main tag but when I inspect the tag, like below,
there's no style applied despite I assigned style "display: flex" to the Container component.
[Devtool says no styled is applied to Container component.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOmfx.png)

I've tried:

- Changing the name of the component.
- Uninstalling and reinstalling styled-components.
- Checking the syntax many times.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following, I was able to render the component and styles no problem:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.main`
  background: red;
  display: flex;
`;

const App = () => {
  return <Container>foo</Container>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Versions:

- React: 17.0.1
- ReactDOM: 17.0.1
- Styled components: 5.2.1

Comment: Hello, I appreciate for your help, Dean.
Problem was solved by creating index.js and let the module read App component.
It makes styled-components regenerate class name and starts working as it was.